# Load local .html file's strings into table view cells

Tags: html, uitableview, html-parsing

iPhone OS Development

I need to set the names of UITableView cells to strings I get from a local "file.html" file.
I know I will need to parse the HTML but I'm not worried about that at the moment.

If someone could show me some quick code that would set the first line of text in the html file and set it to an NSString variable, I think I could figure the rest out.

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to directly manipulate the DOM nodes, but a better approach is to localize the whole `file.html` directly.

Comment: I decided to go with a better approach and save the html locally and then parse it into a plist and load the plist into table view cells.

My reason for this is I will need to use the HTML data frequently and parsing it every time I want info from it would make the app way more complicated then needed.